# ¿Era "se acata pero no se cumple" un dicho común en la América Colonial?

Tags: historia, modismos

Leo en varias partes que el dicho "se acata pero no se cumple" era común durante la Colonia (siglos XVI a XVIII en América Latina) (por ejemplo, página 6 [acá](http://www.madres.org/documentos/doc20101019161226.pdf)). El dicho se refiere a que la Corona en España dictaba leyes que no se cumplían en América. Ejemplos son la protección de indígenas en relación a las encomiendas y otras formas de trabajo forzoso. [Acá](https://cyt-ar.com.ar/cyt-ar/index.php/Se_acata,_pero_no_se_cumple) hay un artículo que cita a un historiador, explicando el origen de esta frase. Un extracto de la cita dice:

> Cuando el virrey o el gobernador recibían una cédula real, emanada del mismo monarca instalado en Madrid, la leía y se daba cuenta de que era un disparate, solemnemente convocaba a los funcionarios, al cabildo, a la Audiencia, al obispo, etcétera, y decía **se acata pero no se cumple**. Es decir, no desconocemos la autoridad del que dice ésto, pero (...) no lo aplico y lo archivo en un cajón. Esto se hizo muchas veces.

Me gustaría ver evidencia de que dicho dicho era usado en ese período. Todo lo que encuentro online son vagas menciones en blogs y artículos ligeros, sin citar referencias. No he logrado encontrar el libro del historiador citado en el link anterior. ¿Alguien podría ayudar a encontrar referencias de dicha frase?

Comment: Encuentro en el CORDE casos similares a «como a tal os obedezcan, respeten y acaten y cumplan vuestros mandamientos» en textos de los siglos XVI y XVII en Perú, Costa Rica, Chile y Puerto Rico. Seguramente fuera una fórmula, lo que haría que ese «acaten y cumplan» acabara siendo respondido con un «se acata pero no se cumple», pero no he encontrado evidencias al respecto. Posiblemente fuera algo de transmisión oral más que escrita.

Comment: Yo pienso que encontrar evidencia es difícil porque para mi es una frase común y corriente y no un "dicho" especial. Es como buscar evidencia del origen de la frase "vamos a jugar a la pelota". Para mi esa frase es análoga a la muy usada hoy **"respeto tu opinion pero no la comparto"** de la cual seguro es también difícil determinar su origen.

Answer (score 1):

https://www.historiadelnuevomundo.com/mito-del-se-obedece-no-se-cumple

...el “obedézcase, pero no se cumpla” era una fórmula administrativa del derecho castellano medieval que tenía como objetivo el comunicar al rey o emisor de una Real Cédula o Provisión Real que la misma era injusta o no se ajustaba a derecho, por lo que la ley capacitaba al receptor a acogerse a obedecer, muestra de respeto al rey, pero no cumplirla. También podía aplicarse en el caso de que tuviese algún tipo de defecto formal o de procedimiento. Con el “pero no se cumpla” no es que se desobedezca, lo que se hace realmente es solicitar la suspensión de su aplicación y su revisión por el rey. Una vez revisada se resolvía ya de forma definitiva, momento en el que ya no cabía el “que no se cumpla”. Por eso cuando alguien utilizaba esta fórmula lo único que hacía era advertir de que esa ley podía ser injusta y solicitar una revisión, cuya resolución final sería aplicada. En muchas casos el legislador en su trabajo provocaba choques normativos de carácter particular con las leyes más generales y esto era advertido y suplicado.

El mismo rey en las Partidas solicita a los alcaldes que si consideran sus disposiciones “contra fuero” no las apliquen y se lo hagan saber:

“Si alguno ganare alguna mi carta que sea contra fuero, e aquel contra qui fuete ganada pudiese mostrar razon derecha que aquella carta es contra fuero, que los alcaldes no usen della, a menos de me lo enviar decir”.

Las primeras disposiciones al respecto se han datado en las Cortes castellanas de 1379 y  1387 y fueron evolucionando a lo largo de los siguientes siglos hasta convertirse prácticamente “en mero trámite inicial del recurso de suplicación” como se dice en las Cortes de Valladolid de 1544, es decir, nada de rebelión contra el rey y contra la corona, un simple trámite para corregir algún error o injusticia, es decir, una fórmula para hacer las leyes más flexibles y más justas.

Vease en más detalle, Benjamín Gonzalez Alonso, AHDE 1980, disponible en https://www.boe.es/publicaciones/anuarios_derecho/articulo.php?id=ANU-H-1980-10046900488